# Updating Links via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am trying to update a file that is linked to three other files using VBA.

My code works, however, it requires all three files paths to be the same. How can I modify my code to allow all three links to be different?

```
Sub UpdateLinks()
    Dim NewLink As Variant
    Dim links As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    links = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
       NewLink = Application.GetOpenFilename
           For i = 1 To UBound(links)
            ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=links(i), NewName:= NewLink, _
               Type:=xlExcelLinks
           Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Move `NewLink = Application.GetOpenFilename` inside the loop?

Comment: When I move NewLink = Application.GetOpenFileName into the loop I have to select the file path for every cell (for over 100 cells). Is there an easier way that I can just select the three unique file paths needed?

Comment: I cannot replicate this. I created a dummy workbook with links to 2 other files, with 20 cells with links. Moving `NewLink = Application.GetOpenFilename` inside the loop, I still only had to select two new file paths.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I forgot to delete the newlink=.... before the loop, so I was getting prompted for the file path more than three time. It’s working now!